# Visual Basic / ASMX - how to use application cache variable?

Tags: vb.net, caching, asmx

I'm trying to amend our content management system so it'll handle SQL database failures more gracefully.  It's a bunch of ASMX pages, and a Helpers.vb file in which I've written a SQL connection tester function.
Each of the ASMX pages call the same function.

I need to create a variable I can check that's persistent and performant, otherwise I'm going to have fall back on something disasterously slow like reading a text file every time I set up a sql connection string.

I've tried using application caching, but either it doesn't work in the context of my helpers.vb file, or I've made a mess of the syntax.  One problem that's already stymied some of the approaches I've found via google - I can't use 'Import System.Web.Caching' - IntelliSense doesn't show the 'Caching' part.

Has anyone got any example code that might get me up and running?  Or an alternative approach?

Comment: When you say 'I've tried using application caching, but either it doesn't work ... or I've made a mess of the syntax', can you post a sample of what you've tried?

Comment: You do have access to HttpContext.Current.Cache or HttpRuntime.Cache within the service, correct?  What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, FYI, ASMX aren't "pages". They are web services.

Comment: I've dumped the code unfortunately, so I can't post it here.  
But I've tried code like 
[code]Dim cache as Cache
cache.Add("sqlStatus", blah blah blah)
[/code]
... with no luck.

I did try using HttpContext, but as (as has been pointed out) these are services not pages and I'm running from a vb class, there is no http context - so it didn't work.   I'd love to retire this application if ASMX is dead, but I don't have time for that right now.

Comment: It's .Net 4.0.3, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Are you able to use HttpRuntime.Cache?  Though, from my understanding, you should still be able to utilize HttpContext, because an asmx is an ASP.NET Service (though obsolete), and must be hosted from and runs in a web context.

Comment: @Mike I don't think so - the httpruntime shows as blue in the import statement, and intellisense doesn't offer .Cache.

Comment: It's not an import.  It would be used directly, like HttpRuntime.Cache("MyKey") = New Object()

Comment: Although, since you are using .NET 4, you may be better off looking into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@Mike,

Many thanks, now I'm using HttpRuntime.Cache correctly... it works!

Thanks everyone for taking the time to post :)